# how to use ilike with Integer in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I use EasyGrid plugin and must find values where integer field like '%001%'

```
initialCriteria {
    ilike('id', "%"+params.id+"%")
}
```

But ilike doesn't work with Integer. How to do it?

I tried to do:

```
    initialCriteria {
        ilike('id'.toString(), "%"+params.id+"%")
    }

    initialCriteria {
        ilike('str(id)', "%"+params.id+"%")
    }
```

but it's not work.

Comment: Did you try to parse it as `String`? `ilike('id', "%" + String.valueOf(params.id) + "%");`

Comment: is `id` an integer in the database?

Comment: I white about first parameter.

Comment: yes. id is integer in database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `id` is an integer in the database, then `ilike` doesn't really make much sense and there is probably a better way to do what you are trying to do (like adding a type field or something to the domain object, and filter by type)

However, you should be able to do something like this (untested):

```
initialCriteria {
    sqlRestriction "cast( id AS char( 256 ) ) like '%001%'"
}
```

Comment: Not working. No signature of method: grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria.sqlRestriction() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [cast( temId AS char( 256 ) ) like '%001%']

Comment: Since this is stated not to work, but has been accepted, would anyone care to update the answer?

Comment: As they accepted it, I assume it did work, and the comment is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Following criteria not working if you search from your textbox when user search any **text character** by **mistake** like **12dfdsf** as your searchable id. It will give you an **exception**

```
initialCriteria {
    ilike('id', "%"+params.id+"%")
}
```

For better use you can use following criteria

```
initialCriteria {
   sqlRestriction "id like '%${params?.id}%'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
String paddedId = params.id.toString().padLeft(3,'0')

initialCriteria {
    ilike('id', "%$paddedId%")
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will work as id is an integer in the domain

Comment: You're right, I focused on params.id conversion, forgetting the actual db column type.

Answer (score 0):

The solution offered by tim_yates with the sqlRestriction would work in version 1.5.0 of easygrid.
One of the main differences from 1.4.x is that the gorm datasource no longer uses DetachedCriteria, but Criteria - which maps directly to Hibernate's Criteria API.

So you can try it on the last version.
(Keep in mind that the upgrade might break your existing grids. There's also many other changes)

Another small observation is that 'initialCriteria' is not the right place to do stuff like that. (it's not wrong, but there is a 'globalFilterClosure' property for applying column independent filters)

Comment: Where I can see documentation or example about 'globalFilterClosure'?

Comment: That would be here: https://github.com/tudor-malene/Easygrid. It behaves exactly like a normal filterClosure. The main difference is that it doesn't belong to any column. It's applied every time you request data.

Answer (score 0):

I mixed the code posted by @tim_yates and mine:

```
String paddedId = params.id.toString().padLeft(3,'0')

def crit = Book.withCriteria {
    sqlRestriction "lpad(cast( id AS char( 256 ) ), 3, '0') like '%${paddedId}%'"
}
```

I've tried with a h2 in-memory db and it works, but I am not sure about two things:

- the real usefulness of that
- `lpad` syntax consistence across all db engines

YMMV

Comment: Note that it could be also written as  `sqlRestriction "lpad(cast( id AS char( 256 ) ), 3, '0') = '$paddedId'"`.